# Probability of an event $A$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set at most countable. Let $X,Y,Z,\xi$ random variables with the following properties:

- $X,Y,Z$ have value in $\mathcal{Z}$
- $\xi\ $ has a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p=1/2$
- $P(X<Y)=1$
- $(X,Y),Z,\xi\ $are independent

We introduce a random variable $M$ and an event $A$ where:
$$
M(\omega)= \begin{cases}Y(\omega)\ \ \ \ \ \text{if }\ \xi(\omega)=1\\X(\omega)\ \ \ \ \ \text{if }\ \xi(\omega)=0\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
A=\{\xi=1,M\ge Z\}\cup\{\xi=0,M<Z\}
$$
Write $P(A)$ in terms of mass function of $X,Y,Z$.

I state that $P(A)=P(Y\ge Z)$ if $\xi(\omega)=1$ or $P(A)=P(X<Z)$ if $\xi(\omega)=0$but i don't know how to go on with the exercise, any ideas or hints?

Comment: In other words you have that: $P(A)=P(Y\geq Z\cap \xi=1)+P(X<Z\cap \xi=0)$ . Now use the (pairwise?) independence.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, but what about $P(Y\ge Z)$ and $P(X<Z)$? How can I write them in terms of $p_Y,p_Z$ and $p_X$?

Comment: The probability space is countably additive. Since $\mathcal Z$ is at most countable, the probability for an event is the sum of the probability masses for each of the atomic outcomes that comprise the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words you have that: $\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(Y\geq Z\cap \xi=1)+\mathsf P(X<Z\cap \xi=0)$ . Now use the (pairwise) independence.

Hint: $\mathsf P(X<Z)=\mathop{\sum\qquad}\limits_{(x,z)\in\mathcal Z^2:x<z}\mathsf P(X=x\cap Z=z)$